# How do I write some excel formulas, See description below

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Is there a formula I can write in "B6" to count the number of cells (in row 3) until 25. I also need a formula in "B7" to return the corresponding year 2023 in "F2".

Comment: So what exactly do you expect to be returned in `B6`? And....what is it you tried yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using INDEX and MATCH:

- `B6`: `=COUNT(C3:INDEX(C3:H3,,MATCH(B5,C3:H3,0)))`
- `B7`: `=INDEX(C2:H2,,MATCH(B5,C3:H3,0))`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What if in B6 I wanted to count the years until a value was >= 23, which in this case will still be 4. However how do I update the formula?

Comment: Perhaps `=COUNT(C3:INDEX(C3:H3,,MATCH(B5,C3:H3,1)))+(COUNTIF(C3:H3,B5)=0)` and `=INDEX(C2:H2,,MATCH(B5,C3:H3,1)+(COUNTIF(C3:H3,B5)=0))`.